# filtering a tibble based on values in a second tibble

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

Given the following tibbles:

```
df1<- tibble(A = c(1:10), B=sample(c(21:30)))
df2<-tibble(A = c(1,2,4,6,7))
```

I want to create df3 which contains all the rows in which df1$A is found in df2$A.  I've tried

```
df3<- df1 %>% filter(A == df2%A))
```

but this returns only 2 rows, because it is matching the rows, not searching for the values.  My real data set is several thousand rows.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df1<- tibble(A = c(1:10), B=sample(c(21:30)))
df2<-tibble(A = c(1,2,4,6,7))
df1 %>% 
  filter(df1$A %in% df2$A)
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to use a [`semi_join()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html)

E.g.,

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df1 <- tibble(A = c(1:10), B = sample(c(21:30)))
df2 <- tibble(A = c(1, 2, 4, 6, 7))

df3 <- semi_join(df1, df2, by = "A")
df3
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       A     B
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1    23
#> 2     2    30
#> 3     4    28
#> 4     6    29
#> 5     7    21
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>